# Stormpath for Django Rest Framework

Tags: django, rest, django-rest-framework, stormpath

We are using Django Rest Framework to build API's that feed AngularJS apps. The intent is to use Stormpath for oauth2 authentication and for storage of backend authorization information. However, all of the examples that I have found using Stormpath with Django are for Django web pages (not REST API's) using username and password, not tokens.

How do you integrate Django REST Framework authentication with Stormpath using oauth2?

Answer (score 3):

In this case, you'll actually be relying on Django Rest Framework for the OAuth2 support -- not Stormpath at all. Stormpath will only provide the User model that DRF uses in the backend -- nothing more.

This was a design decision we made to help simplify the data model.

I'm currently looking into ways to add OAuth2 as a first-class Stormpath feature in Django, but that's a ways down the line currently.